# Crafting times for items not divisible by 1000?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

The PCs in my pathfinder game are crafting magic items and the feat says it takes 1 full day of work to craft per 1000 gold in its base price. I understand that if the market price for an item is 10,000 it would take 5,000 gp and 10 days to craft but what if an item cost 5500? Would it take 5 days beside there are only 5 full sets of 1000 or would I round upthe extra?

Example:
If a PC is crafting a wondrous item and it costs 2500 gp to buy and 1250 to craft how long will it take to make?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation):

> Creating an item requires 8 hours of work per 1,000 gp in the item's base price (**or fraction thereof**), with a minimum of at least 8 hours.

Emphasis mine.  This means you round up.  An item that costs 2001 gp or 2500 gp takes the same crafting time (3 days) as an item that costs 3000 gp.  From the same page:

> Magic supplies for items are always half of the base price in gp. For many items, the market price equals the base price.

So an item that costs 2500 and can be crafted for 1250 takes 3 days to craft.